# Should I mention that I did the pre-revision review of a textbook on my CV?

Tags: united-states, cv, books

Simple question:
Should I mention that I did the pre-revision review of a textbook on my CV? (I suppose this is the revision done before the new edition of a textbook)

They just invited me to do it for a super important textbook in my field of studies.
However, this is the first time that this happened to me and I am wondering whether it is just a survey that has been sent to hundreds of people in the US—if it is so it is not really prestigious, I think.

Answer (score 2):

For a true *review* (see below), then in a section devoted to "other academic work" you could simply write that you are a textbook reviewer for - name of publisher -.  It would be a mistake, I think, to name the book, and the fact that it is a revision is not relevant.

This assumes they have asked you for a real review with suggestions for content changes and such. If it is just a questionnaire, then I'd leave it off the CV completely. As you suspect, it is likely going to a lot of people and part of their motivation is just marketing.